# Corona Slider add listener property after creation

Tags: lua, slider, components, coronasdk

I am trying to add the listener property to a slider component after creation:

```
local function sliderListener( _event )
    print(_event.value)
end

slider = widget.newSlider
{
    top = 30,
    left = 10,
    orientation = "vertical",
    height = 200,
    value = 10,  -- Start slider at 10% (optional)
}

slider.listener = sliderListener
```

However... it doesn't work. Is this impossible or am I using the incorrect syntax?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if the property must exist at creation time. Try:

```
slider = widget.newSlider
{
    top = 30,
    ...
    value = 10,  -- Start slider at 10% (optional)
    listener = sliderListener,
}
```

If you really need to set the handler after creation, instead use the above and set a delegate function to be used by `sliderListener`. For example:

```
local actualListener

function actualListener1(event)
    ...
end

function actualListener2(event)
    ...
end

function sliderListener(event)
    actualListener(event)
end

... create SliderWidget with listener = sliderListener...

actualListener = actualListener2
```

You could also make the `sliderListener` a table that has a `__call` (via `setmetatable(s, {__call = Set.call})`

Comment: That does work - the point is I want to be to remove/add after creation. To be honest I don't think it's possible. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @Oli Not possible to change it that way, but I have updated with one possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the slider listener in tow ways.
     slider = widget.newSlider
     {
       top = 30,
       left = 10,
       orientation = "vertical",
       height = 200,
       value = 10,  -- Start slider at 10% (optional)
       slider.listener = sliderListener
     }

or 
     slider = widget.newSlider
     {
        top = 30,
        left = 10,
        orientation = "vertical",
        height = 200,
        value = 10,  -- Start slider at 10% (optional)
     }
   slider.addEventListener("touch", sliderListener)